# What does buying put option at a certain amount mean?

Tags: options, put-options

Example :
BUY BANK NIFTY 39000 PUT @ 246

In trading platform there is no choice like this. How does one interpret this in simple
language.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? My guess would be that someone bought a PUT option on the BANK NIFTY index with a strike at 39,000 for a 246 premium, but without the context that's just a guess.

Answer (score 10):

> BUY BANK NIFTY 39000 PUT @ 246

It means what it says:

- It's a BUY order for a PUT
- The underlying is the BANK NIFTY
- The strike price is 39,000
- The cost is 246

This entire statement is what a buy order would look like.

If you don't know what these terms mean then you should read about what options are.

Comment: I will add that one essential component was overlooked in the OP's example: The option **expiration date.**

Comment: Yep good point.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.